# How to read time in HH:MM:SS format in Java?

Tags: java, time, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read time in HH:MM:SS format. I tried this but it resulted in java.util.InputMismatchException

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int h = sc.nextInt();
sc.next();
int m = sc.nextInt();
sc.next();
int s = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(h+":"+m+":"+s);
```

Comment: `nextInt()` reads one `int`. `next()` reads to the next token. Which is typically whitespace. So you get `h` and then consume the rest of your `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the default token delimiter, which is whitespace. So `nextInt()` tries to parse the whole date string and fails. Just add the colon as a delimiter, and skip the extraneous `next()` calls:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(":|\\s+");
int h = sc.nextInt();
int m = sc.nextInt();
int s = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(h+":"+m+":"+s);
```

Comment: It is accepting input of the format 12:13:14: rather than the desired input 12:13:14

Comment: I've updated the answer to use colon *or* whitespace as a delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use Java’s standard `LocalTime` class for this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String timeString = sc.nextLine();
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, parseFormat);
    System.out.println(time);
```

No need to reinvent the wheel.

If I enter `9:05:30`, the output is `09:05:30`. If you prefer the output without the leading 0, just format it back to a string with the same `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    System.out.println(time.format(parseFormat));
```

If you need your variables `h`, `m` and `s`, get their values from the `LocalTime` object:

```
    int h = time.getHour();
    int m = time.getMinute();
    int s = time.getSecond();
```

`LocalTime.parse()` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` if the entered string is not a valid clock time. You may want to catch this and act accordingly (for example, print an error message and ask the user to try again).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sc.nextLine to treat the whole thing as a string. After that you search for the ':' with indexOf, and then get your separeted numbers. You can't use nextInt because java will expect integers separeted by spaces not together with ':'

Comment: The more natural solution is to use the SimpleDateFormatter instead of parsing manually.

Comment: @GhostCat sounds like you should write an answer.

Comment: @GhostCat Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The reasonable thing here is to close the question as dup to some scanner and some date format thingy. Which I will do later this morning when I get my hands on a real keyboard :-)

Comment: I recommend `DateTimeFormatter`. I would not find it natural to use `SimpleDateFormat` for any new code in 2017. It has been outdated for years. On the other hand, using the standard library classes is a good idea.